# Outer query is very slow when inner query returns no results

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I'm trying to fetch a row from a table called `export` with random weights. It should then fetch one row from another table `export_chunk` which references the first row. This is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM export_chunk
WHERE export_id=(
    SELECT id FROM export 
    WHERE schedulable=1 
    ORDER BY -LOG(1 - RAND())/export.weight LIMIT 1)
AND status='PENDING' 
LIMIT 2;
```

The `export` table can have 1000 rows while the export_chunk table can have millions of rows.

The query is very fast when the inner query returns a row. However, if there are no rows with `schedulable=1`, the outer query performs a full table scan on `export_chunk`. Why does this happen and is there any way to prevent it?

EDIT: Trying COALESCE()

Akina in the comments suggested using COALESCE, ie.:

```
SELECT * FROM export_chunk
WHERE export_id=COALESCE(
    SELECT id FROM export 
    WHERE schedulable=1 
    ORDER BY -LOG(1 - RAND())/export.weight LIMIT 1)
    ,-1)
AND status='PENDING' 
LIMIT 2;
```

This should work. When I run:

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT id FROM export WHERE schedulable=1 ORDER BY -LOG(1-RAND())/export.weight LIMIT 1), -1) FROM export;
```

It does return -1 for each row which Akina predicted. And if I manually search for -1 instead of the inner query it returns no rows very quickly. However, when I try to use COALESCE on the inner query it is still really slow. I do not understand why.

Comment: Try to wrap your subquery into COALESCE.

Comment: @Akina I did try that but it didn't help. I guess it's because the inner select returns an empty set rather than null but I'm not sure.

Comment: COALESCE will replace empty dataset with definite value. `.. WHERE export_id=COALESCE( (subquery), -1) ..`, or `export_id` instead of `-1`.

Comment: @Akina It looks like you were right about the behavior of COALESCE but it still does not speed up the query. I added an EDIT with more details.

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for each query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this:

```sql
SELECT export_chunk.* 
FROM export_chunk
JOIN ( SELECT id 
       FROM export 
       WHERE schedulable=1 
       ORDER BY -LOG(1 - RAND())/export.weight 
       LIMIT 1 ) AS random_row ON export_chunk.export_id=random_row.id
WHERE export_chunk.status='PENDING' 
LIMIT 2;
```

Does this matches needed logic? especially when no matching rows in the subquery - do you need none output rows (like now) or any 2 rows in this case?

PS. LIMIT without ORDER BY in outer query is strange.

Comment: Ah, yes that works and is fast in both cases! Thank you! Regarding the PS: Yeah, I don't care which chunk I retreive, I just want any chunk that satisfies the constrains.